# MySQL SELECT Field as NULL if NOT Exist in table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, not-exists

**The below query retrieves Quarterly** data for Year 0.  This query successfully retrieves quarters 1, 2, and 3.

```
Year    Quarter    Quarterly_Yield
2012       3             6.6
2012       6             5.58
2012       9             7.28
```

**PROBLEM:** I need to to return 'results' for all four quarters whether or not a data record exists for the quarter.

**DESIRED SOLUTION:** I would like to instruct each Quarterly SELECT field to "RETURN NULL IF NO RECORD EXISTS". This way, my table will contain a result for all 4 quarters, regardless of whether or not the record exists with data.

```
set @ID_CARTERA = 1;

select    

LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4 ) Year,
RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2 ) Quarter,
ROUND ( A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2 ) Quarterly_Yield

from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres A

where     A.ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA
And       LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4 ) = ( select    MAX(left(F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4 ) ) - 0
                                         from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres
                                         where     ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA )
```

Comment: Why have you stored data in a single field?

Comment: I didn't create the database...

Answer (score 0):

For this type of query, you need to set up a driver table that has all the rows that you want in the output.  You can get this by cross joining the year and quarter -- if I understand the data correctly (that is, the quarters are 1, 2, 3, 4 for each year).

The following shows how this is done:

```
select driver.year, driver.quarter,
       ROUND ( A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2 ) Quarterly_Yield
from (select y.year, q.Quarter
       from (select distinct  LEFT(F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4 ) as Year
             from dr_rent_carteras_trimestres
            ) y cross join
            (select distinct  RIGHT(F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2 ) as Quarter
             from dr_rent_carteras_trimestres
            ) q
     ) driver left outer join
     dr_rent_carteras_trimestres A
     on LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4 ) = driver.y and RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2 ) = driver.q
where A.ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA And
      driver.year = (select MAX(left(F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4 ) ) - 0
                     from dr_rent_carteras_trimestres
                     where ID_CARTERA = @ID_CARTERA )
```

Note:  I haven't tested this query so it might have syntax errors.